# Displaying proportional circles with different colors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS and just loaded QGIS this morning.

I would like to display data on a map of Arizona showing power generation type (depicted by color; e.g. coal-black, oil/gas - brown...) and capacity (depicted by a proportionally sized circle).  I have the latitude and longitudinal coordinates of the stations.  I'd also like to have a label for each circle showing the name of the station.

Agua Fria   33.5542 -112.2161   oil/gas 614 MW

Coolidge    32.9175 -111.5041   gas 575 MW

Coronado    34.5778 -109.2717   coal    785 MW

Craig   40.4627 -107.5912   coal    250 MW

Desert Basin    32.9042 -111.7889   gas 581 MW

Four Corners    36.69   -108.4814   coal    154 MW

Gila River  32.9761 -112.694    gas 1650    MW

Hayden  40.4856 -107.185    coal    130 MW

Kyrene  33.3544 -111.9364   oil/gas 410 MW

Mesquite    33.344  -112.8535   gas 625 MW

Navajo  36.9047 -111.3886   coal    969 MW

Palo Verde  33.3869 -112.8626   nuclear 688 MW

Santan  33.3333 -111.751    gas 1219    MW

Springerville   34.3186 -109.1636   coal    417 MW

For the map of Arizona, I would like an outline Arizona.  An added feature would be rivers, lakes, and reservoirs.  In QGIS, I looked at the maps under the web tab and really like Stamen Terrain-USA/OSM map.

Is there a way to control the size of the labels and the visibility of certain labels on the baseline map?

I know nothing about QGIS and it's been ages since I've done any programming.

Comment: Baseline as in rasters? No.

Comment: The baseline I'm referring to is the map I'd start with like the Stamen Terrain-USA/OSM map.  Depending on how far I zoom in or out the text is grainy.  I was wondering if the labels could be removed.

Comment: you mean "basemap" instead of "baseline"; you didn't tell which basemap plugin you are using... openlayers has several bugs, i suggest quickmapservices

Answer (score 0):

first, you should import as comma separated values "csv" your file with the coordinates, (there's an option, a comma sign, which asks you for lat/long x/y fields on your csv; you want two different symbol levels, one is categoric (coal, gas, pv...), the other is numeric (gwh).
For your categorized variable: right click on your layer>properties>style select categorized, select your field and click *classify* and *apply*;
For point size (numeric variable), choose symbol - change option (in the same properties screen), there's a "size" option, click the little window next to it, choose size assistant

Comment: Thank you Elio.  I really appreciate your help.  I made a file with the first 3 stations, exported as a csv from excel, got it into QGIS with the big comma symbol, and got the categoric set, and I though the numeric.  But what I ended up with was one circle in the middle of the world map.  I'll give it another shot :)

Comment: I started from the top and still ended up with the circle in the middle.  I noticed when importing the file that the options were:  point coordinates, well known text, no geometry, DMS.  My lat longs are in decimal degrees, and I selected "point coordinates"  Is this correct?

Comment: did you set the layer's CRS in the import dialogue? it shoulg be lat/long EPSG 4326

Comment: Thank you.  It was not set to EPSG 4326, but I haven't been able to find that.  Could you tell me the other descriptors to find that?  There are lots and lots of CRS selections.  Also

Comment: you may right click on the layer name and then on "set layer crs"

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really appreciate your assistance getting me started!!!